# Make array from AdapterView

Tags: android

Is it possible to get array of views from `onItemSelected()`? because I need to set animation for current view and clear the animation from other views, is it possible?

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adV, View view, int currentIndex, long l) 
        {

                view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(currentContext, R.anim.scale_anim));
                adV[currentIndex + 1].clearAnimation();
                adV[currentIndex - 1].clearAnimation();

        }
```

Comment: `catch NullPointerException`? Are you serious?

Comment: @m0skit0 yup, NullPointerException happened when I change my device orientation from startAnimation() method!

Comment: You should fix your code, not catch an NPE.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What Views you want in the array?

Comment: @m0skit0 Forgot the views,  I want to clear all animation from the views expect the current view.

Comment: Forgot the Views? What's the question then? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the children of the AdapterView like this:

```
int count = adV.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View v = adV.getChildAt(i);
    view.clearAnimation();
}
```

Of course you would need to check also if the view is the current one and skip it.

Comment: Thanks, Work like a charm.